# Why are currents IQ2 and IQ3 in this circuit the same, but is IQ1 larger (image)

Tags: transistors

I was wondering why IQ2 and IQ3 have the same current values, but why the current value of IQ1 is larger. All bases of the bipolar transistors are connected to the same current. I would expect all three currents to be the same

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 2):

Because \$I_{Q1}\$ consist of the collector current of Q1 **plus** the base currents of Q1+Q2+Q3.

> All bases of the bipolar transistors are connected to the same **current**. I would expect all three currents to be the same.

This is not correct. All bases are having the same **voltage**.
If the transistors are identical, the you can indeed except the same collector currents for Q1, Q2 and Q3 because they share the same \$V_{be}\$

Comment: But isn't I_{Q1} providing the bases of Q_{1} Q_{2} and Q_{3} with current

Comment: Yes it does. And **therefore** it is larger than Q2 and Q3.

Comment: Thanks. Did not realise what i just said

Comment: @Huisman It might be nice to include here the very simple to understand idea of using another BJT, in emitter follower form (or common collector if you prefer), that supplies the required base currents. It doesn't completely remove the difference, but it helps a lot and this is a good point to let the OP know about the idea, I think.